# Regexp Emacs for R comments

Tags: regex, r, emacs, lisp, elisp

I would like to build a regexp in Emacs for cleaning up my R code.

One of the problems I ran into was that there are different types of comments:
You have those with a certain amount of whitespace (1), e.g.:

```
        # This is a comment:
# This is also a comment
```

or you have situations like this (2):

```
require(lattice) # executable while the comment is informative
```

The idea is that I want to align the comments when they are of the second kind (after something that's executable), while excluding those of the first kind.

Ideally, it will align all the comments BETWEEN those of the first kind, but not those of the first kind.

Example:

```
funfun <- function(a, b) {
# This is a function
    if (a == b) { # if a equals b
      c <- 1 # c is 1 
    }
  }  
#
```

To:

```
funfun <- function(a, b) {
# This is a function
    if (a == b) { # if a equals b
      c <- 1      # c is 1 
    }
  }  
#
```

I found a regexp to do a replacement for those of the first kind, so then I was able to align them per paragraph (mark-paragraph). That worked kind of well.

Problem is then the backsubstitution:

```
(replace-regexp "^\\s-+#+" "bla" nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

This replaces from the start of a line, with any amount of whitespace and any amount of comment characters like:

```
     #########
```

into

```
     bla
```

The problem is that I would like to replace them back into what they are originally, so "bla" has to go back into the same amount of whitespace and same amount of #.

Hopefully someone understands what I am trying to do and has either a better idea for an approach or knows how to solve this regexp part.

[image]

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you're asking, exactly. You want to replace initial whitespace and the comment marker with some text, then run a transformation on the line, then restore the whitespace and the comment marker?

Comment: @wvxvw I get you wvxcw. It's just that I realised there are only 2 types of comments. So this is the only issue preventing from making a script that would clean any user's needs actually!

Comment: @user4815162342 I actually just want to change those type (1) comments temporarily, to exclude them from aligning the second type per paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's some crazy attempt at doing something I thought you were after. It seems to work, but it needs a lot of testing and polishing:

```
(defun has-face-at-point (face &optional position)
  (unless position (setq position (point)))
  (unless (consp face) (setq face (list face)))
  (let ((props (text-properties-at position)))
    (loop for (key value) on props by #'cddr
          do (when (and (eql key 'face) (member value face))
               (return t)))))

(defun face-start (face)
  (save-excursion
    (while (and (has-face-at-point face) (not (bolp)))
      (backward-char))
    (- (point) (save-excursion (move-beginning-of-line 1)) (if  (bolp) 0 -1))))

(defun beautify-side-comments ()
  (interactive)
  ;; Because this function does a lot of insertion, it would
  ;; be better to execute it in the temporary buffer, while
  ;; copying the original text of the file into it, such as
  ;; to prevent junk in the formatted buffer's history
  (let ((pos (cons (save-excursion
                     (beginning-of-line)
                     (count-lines (point-min) (point)))
                   (- (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point)) (point))))
        (content (buffer-string))
        (comments '(font-lock-comment-face font-lock-comment-delimiter-face)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert content)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      ;; thingatpt breaks if there are overlays with their own faces
      (let* ((commentp (has-face-at-point comments))
             (margin
              (if commentp (face-start comments) 0))
             assumed-margin pre-comment commented-lines)
        (while (not (eobp))
          (move-end-of-line 1)
          (cond
           ((and (has-face-at-point comments)
                 commentp)            ; this is a comment continued from
                                        ; the previous line
            (setq assumed-margin (face-start comments)
                  pre-comment
                  (buffer-substring-no-properties
                   (save-excursion (move-beginning-of-line 1))
                   (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) 
                                   (forward-char assumed-margin) (point))))
            (if (every
                 (lambda (c) (or (char-equal c ?\ ) (char-equal c ?\t)))
                 pre-comment)
                ;; This is the comment preceded by whitespace
                (setq commentp nil margin 0 commented-lines 0)
              (if (<= assumed-margin margin)
                  ;; The comment found starts on the left of
                  ;; the margin of the comments found so far
                  (save-excursion
                    (beginning-of-line) 
                    (forward-char assumed-margin)
                    (insert (make-string (- margin assumed-margin) ?\ ))
                    (incf commented-lines))
                ;; This could be optimized by going forward and
                ;; collecting as many comments there are, but
                ;; it is simpler to return and re-indent comments
                ;; (assuming there won't be many such cases anyway.
                (setq margin assumed-margin)
                (move-end-of-line (1- (- commented-lines))))))
           ((has-face-at-point comments)
            ;; This is the fresh comment
            ;; This entire block needs refactoring, it is
            ;; a repetition of the half the previous blockp
            (setq assumed-margin (face-start comments)
                  pre-comment
                  (buffer-substring-no-properties
                   (save-excursion (move-beginning-of-line 1))
                   (save-excursion (beginning-of-line) 
                                   (forward-char assumed-margin) (point))))
            (unless (every
                     (lambda (c)
                       (or (char-equal c ?\ ) (char-equal c ?\t)))
                     pre-comment)
              (setq commentp t margin assumed-margin commented-lines 0)))
           (commentp
            ;; This is the line directly after a block of comments
            (setq commentp nil margin assumed-margin commented-lines 0)))
          (unless (eobp) (forward-char)))
        ;; Retrieve back the formatted contnent
        (setq content (buffer-string))))
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert content)
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (forward-line (car pos))
    (end-of-line)
    (backward-char (cdr pos))))
```

I've also duplicated it on pastebin for better readability: http://pastebin.com/C2L9PRDM

EDIT: This should restore the mouse position but will not restore the scroll position (could be worked to, perhaps, I'd just need to look for how scrolling is stored).

Comment: An impressive amount of code. :) Do you really need to find comments by their font-lock faces? `forward-comment` uses the built-in syntax scanner.

Comment: `forward-comment` can take a negative count, but I haven't tested it with R, so I don't know how well it works in practice.

Comment: Originally I had a solution where I just used a while loop for it. The problem was that even for a small amount of code, it took about 2 seconds. I assumed with a long buffer it would take a long time. At least, not efficient. With this much code I have a hard time believing it's quick? Is it?

Comment: keeps repeating: 
Continued comment 34 <> 34
pre-comment <  CIupper <- (CI / 100) + CIlower > <- 34

Comment: I didn't know that `forward-comment` won't move backward, but my tests seem to confirm that. Either way, your efforts on the answer make my upvote well deserved.

Comment: Excellent! How come it doesn't bring me back to the point where I called it? save-excursion not working?

Answer (score 1):

`align-regexp` is the awesome bit of emacs magic you need:

```
(defun align-comments ()
  "align R comments depending on whether at start or in the middle."
  (interactive)
  (align-regexp (point-min) (point-max)  
    "^\\(\\s-*?\\)\\([^[:space:]]+\\)\\(\\s-+\\)#" 3 1 nil) ;type 2 regex
  (align-regexp (point-min) (point-max)  
    "^\\(\\s-*\\)\\(\\s-*\\)#" 2 0 nil))                    ;type 1 regex
```

before:

```
# a comment type 1
      ## another comment type 1
a=1 ###### and a comment type 2 with lots of #####'s
a.much.longer.variable.name=2          # and another, slightly longer type 2 comment    
      ## and a final type 1
```

after:

```
      # a comment type 1
      ## another comment type 1
a=1                           ###### and a comment type 2 with lots of #####'s
a.much.longer.variable.name=2 # and another, slightly longer type 2 comment    
      ## and a final type 1
```

Comment: It's close! If you can expand this so that the type 1 comments can still have whitespace before, it's solved (but i think that's where the trouble is).

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly in the scratch buffer, but on the example picture, it also includes the type 1 comments and aligns everything at the level of those type 2.

Comment: Almost there.  We just need the regex expression for type 2 that says match anything but not if it's all whitespace.  Like (.+?)|~(\s-+).

Comment: Maybe edit your answer and include this? Sadly I don't know exactly how/what to change.

Comment: I edited to allow whitespace retention but it's still going to align all the type 1s to a single verticle spot.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(replace-regexp "^\\(\\s-+\\)#" "\\1bla" nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

then

```
(replace-regexp "^\\(\\s-+\\)bla+" "\\1#" nil (point-min) (point-max))
```

but If I understood you well, I would probably do something like :

```
(align-string "\b\s-#" begin end)
```

Comment: align-strings is not a function?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't count the amount of ### needed when you have a code block of #'s (then you have to replace more than one #, but more importantly, how would you get those back?

Comment: The correct function name is align-string (with no s, I've edited my answer)

Comment: align-string does not exist in my Emacs, do you know if it comes with a specific package?

Comment: It's in the "emacs-goodies-el" debian package, and also available at http://www.pvv.org/~markusk/align-string.el That said I believe the solution with align-regexp is probably more flexible.